# Rails: Ajax navigation for user profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

Here's what I want to do:
I have a user profile with a tab like navigation with: "About", "Pictures" and "Comments".

I want to have a partial for each section. So _about.html.erb, _pictures.html.erb and _comments.html.erb. Those partials should load in a div when clicked on the links in the tab-navigation.

Later on I  want to add a loading animation.

Now I'm kind of new to Ajax and tried to find some kind of tutorial or example similiar to this, but I had no luck.

I hope someone can tell me what the best way is. I want to use this kind of loading on alot of other parts in my app so the page doesn't have to reload all the time and it looks cool ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me out:

[Rails 3: Simple AJAXy Page updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016285/rails-3-simple-ajaxy-page-updates)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could start with [jQuery library and .load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/)